# How to write jest test case for drag and drop file in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm new in writing test case, trying to write for drag and drop event while uploading File in react. I've gone through several links but still couldn't find any answer to it using normal react-testing library.

Here is the code:

```
    <div
        className={`dropzone ${isDragging ? "dragging" : ""}`}
        onDragEnter={handleDragEnter}
        onDragLeave={handleDragLeave}
        onDragOver={handleDragOver}
        onDrop={handleDrop}
      >
        <input
          type="file"
          id="input-file-upload"
          className="inputFile"
          data-testid="input-field"
          onChange={handleFileInputChange}
        />
        <label htmlFor="input-file-upload" id="label-file-upload">
          <div>
            <button
              style={{ display: "block", margin: "auto" }}
              onClick={handleButtonClick}
            >
              Add File
            </button>
            {selectedFile ? (
              <p>Selected File: {selectedFile.name}</p>
            ) : (
              <p>Drag and drop files</p>
            )}
          </div>
        </label>
      </div>
```

Here are the dragEnter, DragOver & dragLeave events:

```
 const handleDragEnter = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsDragging(true);
  };

  const handleDragLeave = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsDragging(false);
  };

  const handleDragOver = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  const handleDrop = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsDragging(false);

    const file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
    setSelectedFile(file);
    console.log(file);
  };
```

Here is the whole code:(https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-glade-x9h48c?file=/src/index.js)
Could anyone help me in drag and drop test cases? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code has a runtime error, `file.arrayBuffer is not a constructor`. Please correct it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`fireEvent[eventName]`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events#fireeventeventname) of RTL package.

> `dataTransfer`: Drag events have a `dataTransfer` property that contains data transferred during the operation. As a convenience, if you provide a `dataTransfer` property in the `eventProperties` (second argument), then those properties will be added to the event.

Use `fireEvent.drop()` to trigger the `onDrop` event handler.

E.g.

`index.jsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export function App() {
    const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);

    const handleDragEnter = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setIsDragging(true);
    };

    const handleDragLeave = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setIsDragging(false);
    };

    const handleDragOver = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    const handleDrop = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setIsDragging(false);
        const file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
        setSelectedFile(file);
        console.log(file);
    };

    const handleFileInputChange = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        setSelectedFile(file);
        console.log(file);
    };

    return (
        <div
            className={`dropzone ${isDragging ? 'dragging' : ''}`}
            data-testid='dropzone'
            onDragEnter={handleDragEnter}
            onDragLeave={handleDragLeave}
            onDragOver={handleDragOver}
            onDrop={handleDrop}
        >
            <input
                type='file'
                id='input-file-upload'
                className='inputFile'
                data-testid='input-field'
                onChange={handleFileInputChange}
            />
            <label htmlFor='input-file-upload' id='label-file-upload'>
                <div>{selectedFile ? <p>Selected File: {selectedFile.name}</p> : <p>Drag and drop files</p>}</div>
            </label>
        </div>
    );
}
```

`index.test.jsx`:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import { App } from '.';

test.only('input field onChange', () => {
    render(<App />);
    const dropzone = screen.getByTestId('dropzone');
    expect(screen.getByText('Drag and drop files')).toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.drop(dropzone, { dataTransfer: { files: [new File(['hello'], 'hello.png', { type: 'image/png' })] } });
    expect(screen.getByText('Selected File: hello.png')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76759517/index.test.tsx (8.908 s)
  ✓ input field onChange (43 ms)

  console.log
    File {}

      at handleDrop (stackoverflow/76759517/index.jsx:26:11)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|--------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s  
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|--------------------
All files  |   65.22 |       75 |   33.33 |   65.22 |                    
 index.jsx |   65.22 |       75 |   33.33 |   65.22 | 8-9,13-14,18,30-32 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|--------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.217 s
```

package versions:

```json
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
```