# How to simulate adding a file to FilePond in React Testing Library (RTL)?

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, react-testing-library, filepond

I'm trying to write some unit tests that will cover the function I've written to run during a FilePond `onupdatefiles` unnamed function. I have struggled with actually getting a file added to FilePond in order to trigger my later function. I am asking here if anyone has any experience with simulating adding a file to react-filepond using React Testing Library?

I have tried first a number of ways to reference the FilePond component before falling back to good old `querySelector`. I confirmed via console.log() that it is selecting the  area, but this  area looks very stripped down compared with what I see in the browser, so I'm not sure FilePond is even loading up correctly in my test.

I have tried two different React Testing Library file upload methods, `userEvent.upload()` (https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/v13/#uploadelement-file--clickinit-changeinit--options) and `fireEvent.drop()` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76759675), neither of which seems to have any effect. I've tried adding some extra waiting to let things render, I've tried some variations on `act()` and async/await statements. I'm really struggling with this one, and might be at the point of attempting to just mock out everything expect for `foo()`, so would appreciate any insights.

#### React Component

```js
import React from 'react';

import { FilePond, registerPlugin } from 'react-filepond';
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from 'filepond-plugin-image-preview';
import FilePondPluginFileEncode from 'filepond-plugin-file-encode';

registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImagePreview, FilePondPluginFileEncode);

function MyComponent(props) {

   function foo(encodedFiles) {
      // Does some stuff with the files here, need to test this function `foo`
   }

   return (
      <FilePond
         files={files}
         onupdatefiles={fileItems => {
             try {
                const encodedFiles = fileItems.map(file => file.getFileEncodeDataURL());
                foo(encodedFiles);
              } catch (e) {
                 // See https://github.com/pqina/filepond-plugin-file-encode/issues/22.
                 console.log('Ignoring known cache issue.');
             }
         }}
         allowMultiple={true}
         allowImagePreview={true}
         maxFiles={3}
         instantUpload={false}
         name="files"
         labelIdle='Drag & Drop your files or <span class="filepond--label-action">Browse</span>'
         credits={false}
         className="filepond-upload-area-test"
      />
   );
}
```

#### Test

```js
import React from 'react';
import { act, fireEvent, render, screen, waitFor, within } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

import MyComponent from '../MyComponent';

const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

describe('ImageUploadQuestion component', () => {
    const mockMyComponentProps = {...mocked stuff}

    it('should do stuff with foo() when a file is uploaded', async () => {

        /*
         * Trying userEvent method
         */

        const { container } = render(<MyComponent {...mockMyComponentProps} />);
        const file = new File(['hello'], 'hello.png', { type: 'image/png' })
        const input = container.querySelector('.filepond-upload-area-test');
        await act(async () => {
            userEvent.click(input);
            await userEvent.upload(input, file);
        })
        screen.debug();
    
        // ...
        // expect() foo() output to match expectedOutput
    });

    it('should do stuff with foo() when a file is uploaded, take 2', async () => {

        /*
         * Trying fireEvent method
         */

        const {container} = render(<MyComponent {...mockMyComponentProps} />);
        const input = container.querySelector('[name="files"]')
        fireEvent.drop(input, { dataTransfer: { files: [new File(['hello'], 'hello.png', { type: 'image/png' })] } });
        await delay(3000);
        screen.debug();
    
        // ...
        // expect() foo() output to match expectedOutput
    });
});
```

##### screen.debug() output from above, showing no files added:

```html
<body>
   <div
     class="filepond--wrapper"
   >
     <input
       class="filepond-upload-area-class"
       multiple=""
       name="files"
       type="file"
     />
   </div>
</body>
```